# Determine authorization scopes for a given Github token

Tags: github, github-api

My application uses [Github's Oauth](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/). 
Suppose that:

- in version 1, the app required only basic authorization (scopes = [])
- in version 2, the app required R/W access to public repos (scope = ['public_repo'])

Some users have not logged in yet since the upgrade.

Now I have some tokens with greater authorization capabilities then others. How do I tell them apart?
In other words, how can I ask Github: "Hey, I have this oauth token... what can I do with it?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can make any GitHub API request and read the value of the X-OAuth-Scopes header to see which scopes were supplied with the token. Using /rate_limit won't count against your app's rate limit.

```
curl -I -H 'Authorization: token <token>' https://api.github.com/rate_limit
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2012 23:48:37 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
Content-Length: 61
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.beta
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-OAuth-Scopes: public_repo
Cache-Control: 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test and let you know

Comment: Here is an example how to do it in Ruby http://robert-reiz.com/2013/05/08/determine-scopes-for-given-github-token/

Answer (score 0):

(February 2014): [Enhanced OAuth security for SSH keys](https://github.com/blog/1786-enhanced-oauth-security-for-ssh-keys)

> We just added [more granular permissions](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) so [third party applications](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-with-third-party-applications) can specifically request read-only access, read/write access, or full admin access to your public SSH keys.

---

Note that `access-token` now (October 2013) return scope as well.

This is detailed in "[OAuth changes coming](http://developer.github.com/changes/2013-10-04-oauth-changes-coming/)" (October 2013, by [Tim Cleam - tclem](https://github.com/tclem)):

> Starting today, we are returning granted scopes as part of the access_token response.
>   For example, if you are making a `POST` with the `application/json` mime-type you’ll see an additional field for the granted scopes.

```
{
  "access_token":"e72e16c7e42f292c6912e7710c838347ae178b4a",
  "scope":"repo,gist",
  "token_type":"bearer"
  }
```

> Right now, these scopes will be identical to what you requested, but **we are moving towards a feature set that will allow GitHub users to edit their scopes, effectively granting your application less access than you originally requested**.
>   You should be aware of this possibility and adjust your application behavior accordingly.

#### Some things to watch out for and keep in mind:

> - Most third party applications using GitHub OAuth to identify users have the best success in adoption by starting out with a request for the minimum access that the application can possibly get away with.
>     Something like no scopes or just `user:email` is very sane.
> - It is important to handle the error cases where a users chooses to grant you less access than you originally requested.
>     Now that we are surfacing the granted scopes on the `access_token` response, applications can warn or otherwise communicate with their users that they will see reduced functionality or be unable to perform some actions.
> - Applications can always send users back through the flow again to get additional permission, but don’t forget that users can always say no.